# Woocommerce: New row every nth product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking around the internet for this, but i cannot find a solution. I'm trying to edit the file that displays products (in a theme file called content-product.php). What i want is a new row every fourth product. I'm not really a good programmer and google usually helps me out, but this i cannot find. Anybody got any insights? Here is some code, perhaps anyone can shed some light :)

```
<div class="large-3 columns">
<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

<?php
/**
* woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
*
* @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

<?php
/**
* woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you only want 4 products on a row?

Comment: I basically want a new div every 4 products :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done a number different of ways:

- Add this to the functions.php file

  ```
  // Change number or products per row to 3
  add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
  if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
  function loop_columns() {
      return 4; // 4 products per row
  }
  }
  ```

**OR**

- In the `woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` file change the following line:

  ```
  $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', X* );
  ```

  (*Where X is the value that is already there.)

to

```
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
```

**OR**

- Install and activate [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-archive-customiser/) plug. Then go Woocommerce -> Products, scroll down to the   `Product Columns` heading and change the amount to 4.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I started fiddling with this already. It doesn't work though. I created this thing:

<code>
 $row = array();
 if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
 echo '<div>';
 if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
 echo '</div>';
</code>

That works partly but has flaws.. It generates this:

<div>
three products
</div>

<div>
one product
</div>

<div>
two products
</div>

Comment: New to this site, sorry for the bad comment :-S

Comment: Here, my topic somewhere else: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/output-a-new-row-every-nth-products?replies=2#post-5460188

I am more used to posting there :-)

Comment: Do *not* change `woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`. You can copy that file into your theme's woocommerce folder ex: `your-theme/woocommerce/content-product.php` and make all changes there so that changes aren't lost on upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

```
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'first';
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'last';
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % 4 )
        echo '<div class="row">';
?>
<div class="large-3 medium-3 small-3 columns product-col">
    <div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>

            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>
            <div style="min-height: 40px;" class="headspace">
            </div>
        </a>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % 4 )
        echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 4 items to a row by default now, so if it isn't then it is your theme's style and/or setup that is influencing the product archive.

From `content-product.php`:

```
apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
```

To adjust the number of columns, you would filter it like so from your theme's functions.php

```
function kia_product_columns(){
     return 6;
}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'kia_product_columns' );
```

And remember that your CSS must also be changed accordingly. If you want to display 4 columns, but your CSS is for 3 columns... the 4th product will never appear in the same row.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is not what i was searching for. I wanted the code to output a new (div) row every 4 products. It's been fixed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Like a completely separate div that isn't a shop product? I misunderstood your question then because "new row every nth product" sounds like you wanted to control the number of products per row. Hopefully someone looking to do that will find it useful.

Comment: I wanted to fit the product listing within a responsive framework. So i wanted to create a new div around every four products. I could do that with jquery, but i wanted to do it in the php file so i did not have to wait for jquery to load etc.. This is what i created (i posted an answer.. ;) :

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Next time, if you make your question clearer we might be able to offer more helpful answers.

Comment: I remember those days. Good luck.